# Direct access to USB Printer ports listed in the Windows Spooler

Tags: windows, printing, usb, driver

In the world of printers, particularly the POS ones, there are two common approaches, OPOS and Windows print queues. And there's also the work-around like the virtual serial port. But there seems to be another approach out there too ... the driver is installed but the software seems to be writing directly to the port rather than using the windows spooler.

If you look at the spooler ports when an Epson USB printer is installed for example, there is a ESDPRT001 ... could it be that the POS app is writing to the port directly and bypassing the whole spooler?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Epson's product description of OmniLink](http://pos.epson.com/omnilink/) no driver is required. It is quite possible that the spooler has been outsourced to the powerful onboard computer, which is operating at ~400Mhz. Just a guess.

Comment: I'm more concerned with their standard windows driver model. Omnilink is another ball of wax entirely...

Comment: @Terry Have I understood you correctly that system32/spoolsv.exe is not running?

Not sure what model you are using, but on a thermal T81 connected to ESDPRT001, you would receive an error if the spooler service is not engaged:

 "ERR_SPL_NOT_EXIST -350 The spooler service is not operating."

http://support.epostraders.co.uk/support-files/documents/3/9uC-APD402_T81_Status.pdf

Comment: spoolsv is running. What I've seen is that some programs seem to be able to print to USB printers without using a windows printer per se. What I would like to know is if ESDPRT001 can be written to from user space?

Answer (score 1):

[You don't need a driver for Epson's OmniLink.](http://pos.epson.com/omnilink/) If your spoolsv.exe isn't working, look into [this](http://support.epostraders.co.uk/support-files/documents/3/9uC-APD402_T81_Status.pdf) though.